# There is always a "Nothing" byte at the end of file

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles, eof, stdio

For example this data file `abc.txt`

```
abc
```

Note that there is no newline at the bottom.

When I write the following program in C

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("abc.txt","rb");  // NOTE this is "rb"

    while (!feof(fp)){
        fprintf(stdout, "%c", fgetc(fp));
        fprintf(stdout, "%d", feof(fp));
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The stdout result is like this:

```
[xxx@xxx hello]$ ./a.out 
a0b0c0
0�1[xxx@xxx hello]$
```

What is the additional output bytes in the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`feof` reports whether the EOF indicator has been set, and it's set when you try to read past the end of the file. So the final `fgetc` reads past the end of the file, returns `EOF` (typically -1), and then `feof` returns 1.

This is made more clear if you use `%d` rather than `%c` to show the result of `fgetc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("abc.txt","rb");  // NOTE this is "rb"

    while (!feof(fp)){
        fprintf(stdout, "%d:", fgetc(fp));
        fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", feof(fp));
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
97:0
98:0
99:0
-1:1
```

I'd probably write the code avoiding `feof`, and use that `fgetc` returns EOF when there's an error or the end of the file has been reached.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("abc.txt","rb");  // NOTE this is "rb"

    while (1) {
        int c = fgetc(fp);
        if (c == EOF) break;
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code is still flawed because it treats errors like EOF: you should check if there was a read error using `ferror`.